# XNA 4 objects not moving once GameState has changed from the main menu to playing

Tags: c#, xna

Everything works fine when in GameState.MainMenu but when I click btnPlay (DCButton Class) it switches to GameState.Playing (loads the map/player) but nothing will animate in case GameState.Playing.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case GameState.MainMenu:
            if (btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
            btnPlay.Update(mouse);
            if (btnOptions.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Options;
            btnOptions.Update(mouse);
            if (btnExit.isClicked == true) Exit();
            btnExit.Update(mouse);
            break;
        case GameState.Options:
            break;
        case GameState.Playing:
            player.Update();
            // Exit();
            break;
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

DCPlayer (Class) Update() method consists of getting keyboard input and changing the position of the player. I have also tried this:

```
case GameState.Playing:
    player.Position.X += 1; // <- Position is a Vector2
    break;
```

But this doesn't animate the sprite either. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

NOTE: CurrentGameState is a enum called GameState

EDIT: Draw()

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin();

    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case GameState.MainMenu:
            spriteBatch.Draw(mmBackgroundTexture, mmBackground, Color.White);
            btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
            btnOptions.Draw(spriteBatch);
            btnExit.Draw(spriteBatch);
            break;
        case GameState.Options:
            spriteBatch.Draw(mmBackgroundTexture, mmBackground, Color.White);
            break;
        case GameState.Playing:
            int progress = level.GetLevelProgress();
            level.level = progress;
            level.LoadLevel(); // <- This is where the map gets loaded from the map file
            level.Draw(spriteBatch, Content); // <- This is were the map gets rendered
            player = new DCPlayer(Content, level.grid, graphics.GraphicsDevice); // <- Could this be the problem, I initialized it here because the grid only gets initialized when the map is loaded
            player.Draw(spriteBatch, Content); // <- Draw player in grid using map information (Vector2 DCLevel.Start)
            break;
        }
    spriteBatch.End();


    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Do the values get changed? If this is a drawing issue you should show the `Draw` method too

Comment: @Sayse I have added the draw() method and if you're talking about the values for movement in DCPlayer (Class) player.Update() then yes they get updated (e.g. Position.X += velocity;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your draw method you reassign player to a *new* instance every time which means it never gets chance to use its actual position. By the looks of the code you've shown you can just remove this line from the `Draw` method

```
player = new DCPlayer(Content, level.grid, graphics.GraphicsDevice);
```

Comment: After moving player = new DCPlayer(Content, level.grid, graphics.GraphicsDevice); to the Initialize() method and changing a view things in different classes I finally got this to work. Thankyou for the help!